# Restart during swap of deployment slots

Tags: azure-functions, staging, azure-deployment-slots

I’m trying to reduce the downtime during a deployment to prod without stopping the functions by adding a staging slot. During a swap between production and staging slots, do the functions get automatically restart?

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation of [Swap Operations in Azure Functions deployment slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#swap-operations), restart occurs for every instance in swapping the slots.

The steps given in that document will ensure the target slot doesn't experience downtime during a swap.

In Many Places, the workaround given like adding the app setting `WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG=1` on all slots will ***minimize the restarts but cannot completely avoid***.

Comment: I added the setting but I see this error while running the function and performing a swapping: The orchestrator function 'x' failed: "Failed to deserialize exception from TaskActivity: DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.NonDeterministicOrchestrationException: Non-Deterministic workflow detected: A previous execution of this orchestration scheduled an activity task with sequence ID 0 and name 'x' (version ''), but the current replay execution hasn't (yet?) scheduled this task. Was a change made to the orchestrator code after this instance had already started running?